# XGpio_SetDataDirection, Xilinx, C developer

Tags: c, xilinx, microblaze

My question is, what this function XGpio_SetDataDirection does, en C. For example XGpio_SetDataDirection (&gp_out, 1, 0x00) ?

Comment: With the object &gp_out, I access the device, (The Leds) and what does the other values?

Answer (score 2):

You can find/generate Microblaze drivers' API documentation right from your design. E.g. in Xilinx Platform Studio right clicking on Microblaze core should bring you menu item Driver / View API Documentation. From there you can navigate to `xgpio` driver and for `XGpio_SetDataDirection` you should see something like this:

> ```
> void XGpio_SetDataDirection (XGpio *      InstancePtr,
>                              unsigned     Channel,
>                              u32          DirectionMask
>                             )
> ```
>
> Set the input/output direction of all discrete signals for the specified GPIO channel.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - `InstancePtr`       is a pointer to an XGpio instance to be worked on.
> - `Channel`           contains the channel of the GPIO (1 or 2) to operate on.
> - `DirectionMask`     is a bitmask specifying which discretes are input and which are output. Bits set to 0 are output and bits set to 1 are input.
>
> Returns:
>      None.
>
> Note:
>      The hardware must be built for dual channels if this function is used with any channel other than 1. If it is not, this function will assert.

So in your case `XGpio_SetDataDirection (&gp_out, 1, 0x00)` will set GPIO ports (with your LEDs) as output for your Microblaze CPU core.

Answer (score 0):

It's a library function. This can be viewed in xgpio.c file.
Here is a definition of this guy:

```
  void XGpio_SetDataDirection(XGpio *InstancePtr, unsigned Channel,
                u32 DirectionMask)
{
    Xil_AssertVoid(InstancePtr != NULL);
    Xil_AssertVoid(InstancePtr->IsReady == XIL_COMPONENT_IS_READY);
    Xil_AssertVoid((Channel == 1) ||
             ((Channel == 2) && (InstancePtr->IsDual == TRUE)));

    XGpio_WriteReg(InstancePtr->BaseAddress,
            ((Channel - 1) * XGPIO_CHAN_OFFSET) + XGPIO_TRI_OFFSET,
            DirectionMask);
}
```